# T-SQL Conditional Max or Sum based on group criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregates

I have not been able to figure this out and I want to find out the most efficient way of doing this.  I have this table (partial records shown):

```
prefix  FolioNumber  CmmtAmount  CmmtNumber
------- -----------  ----------  ----------
100981  10098100005         1    100981100
100981  10098100006         3    100981100
100981  10098100007         9    100981100
100981  10098100009         2    100981100
100981  10098100010         6    100981100
600499  60049900001         0    NULL
600499  60049900003         2    600499300
600499  60049900004         5    600499500
```

From that table I need to come up with this result set:

```
prefix  CmmtAmount
------  ----------
100981         9
600499         7
```

This is the logic:

For each **prefix**:

- if there are multiple but identical **CmmtNumber** records, pick the
  one with the MAX(**CmmtAmount**)
- if there are multiple but different    **CmmtNumber** records,
  display the SUM(**CmmtAmount**) for all those records.

I've been looking at OVER/PARTITION but can't come up with the right query. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Would you consider NULL a value here? So if there is a prefix only with `CmmtNumber` 123456 and NULL, would you want `MAX(CmmtAmount)` or `SUM(CmmtAmount)`?

Comment: What if there are multiple identical and different cmmtNumbers for the same Prefix?

Comment: @Nikolaus: that's a good point. Not sure if that scenario will come up, but how would I handle it, if it did?  Thanks for your answer, too, by the way.

Comment: cheluto2: You can use `COUNT(CmmtNumber)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT CmmtNumber)` to check this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
select
  prefix,
  case when min(CmmtNumber) = max(CmmtNumber) then max(CmmtAmount) 
                                              else sum(CmmtAmount) 
  end as CmmtAmount
from mytable
group by prefix
order by prefix;
```

Comment: Man! Sometimes the logic is much simpler than it seems. I was trying to complicate it too much. Thank you very much, this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if I understand your requirements completely, but I'll give it a try:

```
SELECT Prefix, MAX(CmmtAmount) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY Prefix
HAVING MIN(CmmtNumber)=MAX(CmmtNumber)
UNION 
SELECT Prefix, SUM(CmmtAmount) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY Prefix 
HAVING MIN(CmmtNumber) != MAX(CmmtNumber)
```

I hope, this works for you.